# StringIndexout of range

Tags: java, exception, indexing

I got an error: StringIndex out of range: -1 with error line is  String anEmail = lineFromFile.substring(s+1, e). As you can see im trying to print a part of a line in an input file but i doesn't work. Can someone help me explain why?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Email13 
{
    static boolean isValidEmailCharacter(char c)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        if((c>='A'&&c<='Z')||(c>='a'&&c<='z')||(c>='0'&&c<='9')||(c=='.')||(c=='-')||(c=='+'))
            result = true;
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    BufferedReader cin, fin;
    cin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    //Description
    System.out.println("Programmer: Minh Nguyen");
    System.out.println("Description: This program is to start the final project.");
    System.out.println();    

    String nameIn, nameOut, deIn, deOut;
    nameIn="";
    nameOut="";
    deIn = "fileContainingEmails.txt";

    System.out.print("Enter input filename [default:" + deIn + "]: ");
    nameIn = cin.readLine();

    if(nameIn.compareTo("")==0){
        nameIn = deIn;
      deOut = "copyPasteMyEmails.txt";
        System.out.print("Enter output filename [default:" + deOut + "]: ");
        nameOut = cin.readLine();
        if(nameOut.compareTo("")==0)
          nameOut = deOut;
    }
    else if(nameIn.compareTo("")>0){
        deOut = nameIn;
        System.out.print("Enter output filename [default:" + deOut + "]: ");
        nameOut = cin.readLine();
        if(nameOut.compareTo("")==0)
          nameOut = nameIn;
    }
    fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nameIn));
    //Read the input file
    while(true)
    {
        if(!fin.ready()) break;
        String lineFromFile;
        lineFromFile = fin.readLine();
        int s, e, hasDot;

        for (int i = 0; i < lineFromFile.length(); i++) // for each char in the string...           
        {
      if(lineFromFile.charAt(i)=='@')
      {
          for(s=i;s>-1;s--)
          {
              if(isValidEmailCharacter(lineFromFile.charAt(s))==false)
                  for(e=1; e< lineFromFile.length(); e++)
                  {
                      if(isValidEmailCharacter(lineFromFile.charAt(e))==false)
                      {
                          String anEmail = lineFromFile.substring(s+1, e);
                          System.out.println(anEmail);
                          break;
                      }

                  }
          }



      }                                                               

      }

  }
     fin.close();

    PrintWriter fout;
    fout = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(nameOut));
    fout.close();        
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose a line has 10 characters. So `i` loop goes from 0 to 9.

You then have a `s` loop, which goes from `i` to 0.

And inside that, you access `linefromFile.subString(s+1);

So when `i` is 9, your `s` loop starts at 9, and you try to access index 9+1, which is index 10, which is outside of your line.

Comment: But even if I use String anEmail = lineFromFile.substring(s,e), it still fails with an error: StringIndex out of range: -8 with error line. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Since Arrays are zero based indices, your `lineFromFile.substring(s+1, e)` is throwing an error.

```
for(s=i;s>-1;s--){
    //lines of code
    String anEmail = lineFromFile.substring(s+1, e)
```

This would fail for `i = lineFromFile.length`

as it would translate to `lineFromFile[i+1]` where `lineFromFile[i]` is the last element.

Comment: But even if I use String anEmail = lineFromFile.substring(s,e), it still fails with an error: StringIndex out of range: -8 with error line. How can I fix this?